# Postfix/ Dovecot and MySQL

Tags: mysql, postfix

I have an issue in authenticating users using postfix/ dovecot with mysql at ubuntu LTS. Outlook connected to the server but got error for authentication.

below is posfix configuration settings:

```
       append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 0
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128, 144.122.116.0/24
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = /etc/mailname
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = [smtp.buyorsell.it]:587
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, rej                                             ect_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks,permit
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:$config_directory/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.                                             cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

and then dovecot configuration shows like this:

```
    root@server:~# dovecot -n
# 2.0.19: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
doveconf: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -n > dovecot-new.conf
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf:124: add auth_ prefix to all settings inside auth {} and remove the auth {} section completely
doveconf: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -n > dovecot-new.conf
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf:124: add auth_ prefix to all settings inside auth {} and remove the auth {} section completely
# OS: Linux 2.6.32-042stab088.4 x86_64 Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS simfs
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
protocols = imap pop3 sieve
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0604
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmails
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocol imap {
  imap_client_workarounds = delay-newmail
  mail_max_userip_connections = 10
}
protocol pop3 {
  mail_max_userip_connections = 10
  pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
}
protocol lda {
  deliver_log_format = msgid=%m: %$
  mail_plugins = sieve
  postmaster_address = postmaster
  quota_full_tempfail = yes
  rejection_reason = Your message to <%t> was automatically rejected:%n%r
}
```

My error log is `/var/log/mail.log`:

```
Sep 30 08:22:10 server postfix/submission/smtpd[1466]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
Sep 30 08:22:10 server postfix/submission/smtpd[1466]: connect from unknown[182.186.87.163]
Sep 30 08:22:11 server postfix/submission/smtpd[1466]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth? Basic SPAM prevention failed: No such file or directory
Sep 30 08:22:11 server postfix/submission/smtpd[1466]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Sep 30 08:22:12 server postfix/master[1448]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 1466 exit status 1
Sep 30 08:22:12 server postfix/master[1448]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Sep 30 08:22:45 server dovecot: auth-worker: mysql(127.0.0.1): Connected to database mailserver
Sep 30 08:23:05 server dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 3 attempts): user=<route36@buyorsell.it>, method=PLAIN, rip=182.186.87.163, lip=162.250.122.195, TLS
```

It is master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy

submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING


#submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  
##spamassassin unix - n n - - pipe 
##user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e 
##usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
# # -o content_filter=spamassassin
#  #-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
##  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
dovecot unix - n n - - pipe
 flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

I need incomming/ outgoing mails get starts working.

Comment: "an issue"? Could you be more specific?

Comment: sasl authentication. Let me know what info you required

Comment: Could you describe the problem as exactly as if you were trying to explain to an six-year-old what you're trying to do. Include every necessary information: Where exactly does the error occur, what did you do, etc. Please edit your post to add more information.

Comment: Configured postfix/ dovecot as instructed in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassasin while connected via outlook and mozilla thunderbird but user is not being authenticated. But connected

Comment: When trying to authenticate, please send the output of `tail -f /var/log/mail.log`

Comment: @HafizMuhammadMuazzam please add this to your question by editing it.

Comment: Can you show the mail.log from the time when dovecot is starting?
The problem is anyway that postfix, for some reason, doesn't see the dovecot auth listener. Is it in place, where you configured it to be? Maybe it's permissions issue? Also, can you show postfix config, for more complete picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two actions get resolved the issue.

Removed value of:

```
relayhost = [smtp.buyorsell.it]:587
```

as

```
relayhost =
```

and uncomment

```
spamassassin unix - n n - - pipe
```

in master.cf

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problem with mysql connection now (where you keep user db, as far as I see).
You should check permissions in mysql for dovecot to connect (user vmail) to the proper database.

grant all privileges on your_database.* to 'vmail'@'localhost';

(assuming here that the database is local to dovecot, also all privileges may be a bit too broad for what you may really need - I guess actually select would be enough?)

Comment: Yes it helps me to correct user in dovecot.

Comment: Now getting error server postfix/submission/smtpd NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[xxx]: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[xxx]>: Client host rejected: Access denied;

Comment: Has the client authenticated properly? With this little information there's not much I can tell, except that connection has been rejected, probably either for lack of proper authentication or email to unauthorized destination.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth Basic SPAM prevention
```

remove that `"Basic SPAM prevention"`, leaving only

```
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
```

Then restart postfix.

Comment: This not resolved the issue.

Comment: What's the error like now?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/531450/postfix-submission-smtpd-relay-access-denied/531460#531460. But this error is not after above change.

Comment: Looking at the other thread I'd say you have kind of mix up in configs. First of all anyway - can you tell which version of postfix you use?  Also - add master.cf somewhere to allow us review configs. Have you configured submission port properly?

Comment: OK - can you add -v, for debug, to smtpd in smtp and submission sections, restart postfix and also paste log from connection attempts, to make it easier to tell which restriction rejects you?

Comment: Speaking yet of your "Relay access denied" - are you sure you're rejected by your server, not the relay host, you configured in your main.cf? Are you allowed to send through smtp.buyorsell.it, especially on submission port?

Comment: for relay access denied, I have mistakenly typed cyrus instead of dovecot in ssl_type property. So that issue get resolved now.