# postfix/submission/smtpd Relay Access Denied

Tags: postfix

Getting error 'Relay access denied'

At outlook, set port 587 for smtp and 993 for imap at Ubunut LTS.

My configuration is:

```
    root@server:~# postconf -n
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 0
mydestination =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = /etc/mailname
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks,permit smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:$config_directory/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

corrected

```
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
```

to

```
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
```

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to your `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_destination
```

Comment: Got this:postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination

Comment: You are probably using Ubuntu 12.04. Then replace `smtpd_relay_restrictions` with `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.

Comment: added smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,  reject_unauth_destination but same issue.